# How to provide dependency JARs to Jenkins for building Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pom.xml

I have a Maven project that uses two dependency JARs which I built in my local environment. But, when I am trying to build the Maven project (clean install), it is failing since it is unable to find those two JARs. How do I pass those two JARs?

The project is pulled from Git and then built. It is working fine unless there are dependency JARs.

Comment: Jenkins used to have a plugin to make it function as a Maven repository for built artifacts.  That may be very useful to you.

Comment: Can you specify the name? Cannot find!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Maven, you draw your dependencies from a Maven repository. Many jars can be drawn from MavenCentral. In a company environment, you usually run your own Nexus/Artifactory, in which you manage your artifacts (that you built) and the external dependencies. This is the best place for your JARs.

Answer (score 3):

The common practice today is to upload it to some artifact storage (Nexus, Artifactory, Azure Devops Feed and so on). 
If you have no one, you can install those jars to your local repository (on jenkins slave or master. You must copy your jars before.) using [Maven Install Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) .

Comment: Not able to find this plugin in the "Available" list.

Comment: Oh... It's not a Jenkins plugin. It's a maven one.  It means, you should connect to jenkins executor (ssh, remote desktop or whatever) and run a maven command (mvn install ....). You can also do it from job, like execute bash script. But jars should be installed only once, so running it from terminal seems to be preferable.